# Is it possible to use ViBe algorithm, implemented in opencv, for systema without GPU?

Tags: opencv, motion-detection, background-subtraction, blobs

I want to test ViBe algorithm for Background Subtraction. Currently I am using opencv libraries. I found out a sample implementation in opencv/samples/gpu/bgfg_segm.cpp and bgfg_vibe.cpp files. These files are under gpu module. Now I have a system without GPU. And when I try to run the code, it crashes on the initialization of the first frame. Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pseudo codes suck big time! here's the un-pseudo/ed version. results?:there is only try or try not

bgfg_vibe.hpp

```
#ifndef bgfg_vibe_hpp
#define bgfg_vibe_hpp
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

struct Model {
    cv::Mat*** samples;
    cv::Mat** fgch;
    cv::Mat* fg;
};

class bgfg_vibe
{
#define rndSize 256
    unsigned char ri;
#define rdx ri++
public:
    bgfg_vibe();
    int N,R,noMin,phi;
    void init_model(cv::Mat& firstSample);
    void setphi(int phi);
    cv::Mat* fg(cv::Mat& frame);
private:
    bool initDone;
    cv::RNG rnd;
    Model* model;
    void init();
    void fg1ch(cv::Mat& frame,cv::Mat** samples,cv::Mat* fg);
    int rndp[rndSize],rndn[rndSize],rnd8[rndSize];
};

#endif
```

bgfg_vibe.cpp

```
#include "bgfg_vibe.hpp"

bgfg_vibe::bgfg_vibe():R(20),N(20),noMin(2),phi(0)
{
    initDone=false;
    rnd=cv::theRNG();
    ri=0;
}
void bgfg_vibe::init()
{
    for(int i=0;i<rndSize;i++)
    {
        rndp[i]=rnd(phi);
        rndn[i]=rnd(N);
        rnd8[i]=rnd(8);
    }
}
void bgfg_vibe::setphi(int phi)
{
    this->phi=phi;
    for(int i=0;i<rndSize;i++)
    {
        rndp[i]=rnd(phi);
    }
}
void bgfg_vibe::init_model(cv::Mat& firstSample)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    split(firstSample,channels);
    if(!initDone)
    {
        init();
        initDone=true;
    }
    model=new Model;
    model->fgch= new cv::Mat*[channels.size()];
    model->samples=new cv::Mat**[N];
    model->fg=new cv::Mat(cv::Size(firstSample.cols,firstSample.rows), CV_8UC1);
    for(size_t s=0;s<channels.size();s++)
    {       
        model->fgch[s]=new cv::Mat(cv::Size(firstSample.cols,firstSample.rows), CV_8UC1);
        cv::Mat** samples= new cv::Mat*[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            samples[i]= new cv::Mat(cv::Size(firstSample.cols,firstSample.rows), CV_8UC1);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<channels[s].rows;i++)
        {
            int ioff=channels[s].step.p[0]*i;
            for(int j=0;j<channels[0].cols;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<1;k++)
                {
                    (samples[k]->data + ioff)[j]=channels[s].at<uchar>(i,j);
                }
                (model->fgch[s]->data + ioff)[j]=0;

                if(s==0)(model->fg->data + ioff)[j]=0;
            }
        }
        model->samples[s]=samples;
    }
}
void bgfg_vibe::fg1ch(cv::Mat& frame,cv::Mat** samples,cv::Mat* fg)
{
    int step=frame.step.p[0];
    for(int i=1;i<frame.rows-1;i++)
    {
        int ioff= step*i;
        for(int j=1;j<frame.cols-1;j++)
        {
            int count =0,index=0;
            while((count<noMin) && (index<N))
            {
                int dist= (samples[index]->data + ioff)[j]-(frame.data + ioff)[j];
                if(dist<=R && dist>=-R)
                {
                    count++; 
                }
                index++;
            }
            if(count>=noMin)
            {
                ((fg->data + ioff))[j]=0;
                int rand= rndp[rdx];
                if(rand==0)
                {
                    rand= rndn[rdx];
                    (samples[rand]->data + ioff)[j]=(frame.data + ioff)[j];
                }
                rand= rndp[rdx];
                int nxoff=ioff;
                if(rand==0)
                {
                    int nx=i,ny=j;
                    int cases= rnd8[rdx];
                    switch(cases)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        //nx--;
                        nxoff=ioff-step;
                        ny--;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //nx--;
                        nxoff=ioff-step;
                        ny;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //nx--;
                        nxoff=ioff-step;
                        ny++;
                        break; 
                    case 3:
                        //nx++;
                        nxoff=ioff+step;
                        ny--;
                        break; 
                    case 4:
                        //nx++;
                        nxoff=ioff+step;
                        ny;
                        break; 
                    case 5:
                        //nx++;
                        nxoff=ioff+step;
                        ny++;
                        break; 
                    case 6:
                        //nx;
                        ny--;
                        break; 
                    case 7:
                        //nx;
                        ny++;
                        break; 
                    }
                    rand= rndn[rdx];
                    (samples[rand]->data + nxoff)[ny]=(frame.data + ioff)[j];
                }
            }else
            {
                ((fg->data + ioff))[j]=255;
            }
        }
    }
}
cv::Mat* bgfg_vibe::fg(cv::Mat& frame)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    split(frame,channels);
    for(size_t i=0;i<channels.size();i++)
    {
        fg1ch(channels[i],model->samples[i],model->fgch[i]);        
        if(i>0 && i<2)
        {
            bitwise_or(*model->fgch[i-1],*model->fgch[i],*model->fg);
        }
        if(i>=2)
        {
            bitwise_or(*model->fg,*model->fgch[i],*model->fg);
        }
    }
    if(channels.size()==1) return model->fgch[0];
    return model->fg;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bgfg_vibe.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Mat frame;
    bgfg_vibe bgfg;
    VideoCapture cap("c:/toprocess/frame_%04d.jpg");
    cap >> frame;
    bgfg.init_model(frame);
    for(;;)
    {
        cap>>frame; 
        Mat fg = *bgfg.fg(frame);
        imshow("fg",fg);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its been so long. Well, I have not tested the above implementation of ViBe But it seems very helpful. At least, The code above is non-gpu version of ViBe and represent the pseudo code from the paper. So, those who are interested, can give a try on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code @Zaw Lin. It works perfectly. However, I notice something which I'm not sure. In bgfg_vibe.cpp should this line:
    model->samples=new cv::Mat**[N];
be:
model->samples=new cv::Mat**[3]; // for 3-channel image.

Comment: hi, N is correct.  for multi channel images, each channel is treated as gray and the implementation simply initialize individual models for each channel.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you: want to use Vibe without GPU in OpenCV. Unfortunately, there's no non-gpu implementation in current version of OpenCV(2.4.3). If I'm wrong, please let me know. So I implemented the vibe myself base on the pseudo code presented in the paper. It's not as difficult as I thought.

And I'm happy with this algorithm so far. It's great in general, but I think there still needs some further works to conquer the ghost problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Btw how was your experience with the pseudo code? I mean, can you tell me some kind of statistics or something, like resolution vs. fps? I have implemented MOG and I am getting upto 30 fps for 640 X 480 resolution frames with learning parameter set to 0. Do you think that PBAS can resolve the ghost problem in its own manner?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ViBE is patented and that its uses is subject to licensing fees. Please go to vibeinmotion.com for a trial version and more info. I am in charge of the business development of ViBE and you can contact me directly for more info. Regards.

Comment: A website with full of SQL exceptions, no information exist.